# Collecting malware samples

Tags: malware

Could you please list some sites from where I could download viruses/worms/trojans in **.exe** format. I have read the answers to the other similar questions but couldn't make much use of them. 
I am a novice at dynamic analysis of malware and it's easier for me to analyse the malware samples on my virtual machine if they are in .exe format.

Comment: I have read the answers to that question and none of the links were helpful. I don't think it's fair to flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: have you tried vxheaven?